# How coturn works?

Tags: webrtc, rfc5766turnserver, coturn

I was read the turnserver [rfc-5766](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5766.txt). In this the figure 1 the following are the things are gets take placed.

```
Turn server
Turn client
Peer A
Peer B
```

My understanding is the peer A and peer B are used for the webrtc clients who wants to communicate each other behind a symmetric NAT. They uses the turn server to communicate.

But I don't know what is the use of turn client in here. Then  I did not understand what is the use of send indication and data indication. They said the data is transfered using the allocated relayed address. But that address is not yet used. But the the data transferring is gets successful. I don't know how it gets succeed. Please explain me the flow of the coturn 4.5.0.3 turn server.